# How to move a Reminder from one list to another in iOS?

Tags: ios, reminders

There doesn't appear to be an option in Reminders to 'move to another list'

Is it really just a case of copy and paste, which would be pretty terrible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using iOS 6.1.2 it is pretty straight forward (I have no older version of iOS with me to check how and if it works there, but I guess it will).

Tab on the task/reminder you would like to move to another list. Choose *more options* or *show more* (my language setting is German so I'm not 100% sure how this menu item is called in english). There appears an option titled *List*. This will allow you to move the item to another list.

[image: Choose task]
[image: Choose more...]
[image: Change list]

Comment: Unfortunately moving single reminder items is limited to lists from the same account only. :-(

Answer (score 0):

My iPad is currently at IOS 9.1. I was able to move an item from one list to another by

1. Clicking edit (upper right corner)
2. Selecting the red symbol to the left of the item
3. Choosing the "More" option (in gray)
4. Clicking "list" (fourth option down from the top)
5. Choosing the list to which you would like to change your item.

Hope this helps!